# cordova: losing window.cordova after navigating to external url

Tags: cordova

```
window.cordova
```

gives **undefined** after I navigate to external url such as:

```
window.location.href = "http://example.com";
```

(I also tried with window.open etc..)

Is there a way to keep reference to cordova on external url ?

Comment: you may have to use inappbrowser plugin to open external URL in that case

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the allow-navigation tag. So to solve it I only had to put the

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

tag into the project's config.xml file.

Comment: Plus 1 because it helps me

Answer (score 0):

`window.cordova` And also other cordova based functions are based on cordova.js file included to your cordova Application.

1-It's not safe to include this file to your site since some plugin dependent functions might not work correctly , but in your case try to add its script tag to external site if you have access to source :

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

2-Second approach  might be better : use iframe inside your cordova App and load the external url there , because you've imported cordova.js before the iframe `window.cordova` now should work correctly.